# Program execution not stopping at scanf() after first read

Tags: c++, string, enums

I want that at every iteration of the do-while() loop the program stops at the scanf() function, but the program loops the same amount of times as the number of white spaces that the read string contains before stoping again at the scanf()

```
enum Comando
{
    AYUDA,
    LOGIN,
    LOGOUT,
    LISTAR_BUSES,
    LISTAR_RUTAS,
    LISTAR_VIAJES, 
    NULL_COMMAND 
};

//Funcion que registra el comando ingresado por el usuario para indicarle al programa que es lo que debe hacer
pair<Comando, queue<char*>> ProcesarComando(char comandoEntero[20]);
void MostrarAyuda();

int main()
{
    bool salir = false;
    char comando[20];
    Comando cmd;

    do
    {
        printf("\n\t$ ");
        scanf(" %s", comando);

        cmd = ProcesarComando(comando).first;

        switch(cmd)
        {
            case AYUDA:

            break;
            case LOGIN:

            break;
            case LOGOUT:

            break;
            case LISTAR_BUSES:

            break;
            case LISTAR_RUTAS:

            break;
            case LISTAR_VIAJES:

            break; 
            case NULL_COMMAND:

            break;           
        }
    }
    while(!salir);

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}

pair<Comando, queue<char*>> ProcesarComando(char comandoEntero[20])
{
    int pos = 0;
    char *argumento, *comandoNombre;
    bool tieneParametros = false;
    pair<Comando, queue<char*>> retorno;

    argumento = new char[20];
    
    while(comandoEntero[pos] != '\0')
    {
        if(comandoEntero[pos] == '<'|| comandoEntero[pos] == '[')
        {
            tieneParametros = true;
        }
        else if(tieneParametros && comandoEntero[pos] != ' ' && comandoEntero[pos] != '<' && comandoEntero[pos] != '>' && comandoEntero[pos] != '[' && comandoEntero[pos] != ']')
        {
            strncat(argumento, &comandoEntero[pos], 1);
        }
        else if(tieneParametros && comandoEntero[pos] == ' ')
        {   
            cout<<"HOLAAAAAAA";
            retorno.second.push(argumento);
            memset(argumento, '\0', strlen(argumento));
            tieneParametros = false;
        }
        pos++;
    }

    comandoNombre = new char[20];
    comandoNombre = strtok(comandoEntero, " ");

    if(strcmp(comandoNombre, "ayuda") == 0)
    {
        retorno.first = AYUDA;
        return retorno;
    }
    else if(strcmp(comandoNombre, "login") == 0)
    {
        retorno.first = LOGIN;
        return retorno;
    }
    else if(strcmp(comandoNombre, "logout") == 0)
    {
        retorno.first = LOGOUT;
        return retorno;
    }
    else if(strcmp(comandoNombre, "listar_buses") == 0)
    {
        retorno.first = LISTAR_BUSES;
        return retorno;
    }
    else if(strcmp(comandoNombre, "listar_rutas") == 0)
    {
        retorno.first = LISTAR_RUTAS;
        return retorno;
    }
    else if(strcmp(comandoNombre, "listar_viajes") == 0)
    {
        retorno.first = LISTAR_VIAJES;
        return retorno;
    }

    // printf("\n%s", retorno.second.front());
    // retorno.second.pop();
    // printf("\n%s", retorno.second.front());

    retorno.first = NULL_COMMAND;
    return retorno;
}
```

So, because the program is not stoping at the scanf(), it is printing all those money signs but without letting me interact with the program until the amount of the string white spaces are reached...

[image: Image of the obtained output:]

I know that it may be something dumb, but couldn't figure it out, hope that you guys could help me.THANKS :v

Comment: @S.M. It is printing the same output

Comment: `while(!salir);` The posted code will run an infinite loop, because `salir` is never changed inside the loop. Please post the real code, including the definitions of `Comando`, `AYUDA` etc.

Comment: (a) Test the value returned by `scanf()` — if it isn't `1`, you've got problems.  (b) Print the value set in `comando` by `scanf()`.  Use `printf("comando = [%s]\n", comando);` before calling `ProcesarComando()`.  That will give you information about what's happening.

Comment: You need to know which language you are learning and programming in.  The notation `pair<Comando, queue<char*>> ProcesarComando(char comandoEntero[20]);` is not valid C; it looks like C++.  Why would you tag C++ code as C? And don't forget to finish printing operations with newlines.  If you don't, line buffering leaves the last incomplete line stuck inside the program until you add a newline.

Comment: @dxiv Done all of the code is right there know. I did not chage the value of "salir" variable yet because first i'm trying to figure out why the program is not stoping at the scanf() function as it should.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have tried what you said, the scanf() is not reading all of the string it is just reading all the characters that are before the white spaces and then continue with the rest of them one by one (if they're white spaces). Is that the way that scanf() or cin>> works? Should I be using something like cin.getline() or something like that if I want to read absolutely all the string from the user? Sorry for all the dumb questions but It's been a long time since I use C++ and I have forgotten pretty much everything about strings. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Dacaramo  Note that the `%s` format specifier reads a string delimited by whitespace. Assuming the first line in the screenshot `"ayuda <> <> <> <> <>\n"` is what you enter when prompted, `scanf` will parse that as the string `"ayuda"` followed by 5 identical strings `"<>"`.

Comment: @dxiv I see, thanks for the help men, so what's in your opinion the best way to get all of the input written by the user? (Asuming that i'm in C++ and i'm not restricted to only use scanf())

Comment: @Dacaramo The C++ way would be [`cin.getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), the C way a [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) with a `" %[^\n]"` format string (or similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am posting a proper C++ implementation of your code. I know that code-only answers are not recommended. But here, I don't have much to tell you. You need to yourself check about the things you lack knowledge about. Better search things on this [site](https://es.cppreference.com/w/).

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

enum Comando {
    AYUDA,
    LOGIN,
    LOGOUT,
    LISTAR_BUSES,
    LISTAR_RUTAS,
    LISTAR_VIAJES,
    NULL_COMMAND
};

auto ProcesarComando(std::string comandoEntero) {

    std::string argumento, comandoNombre;
    bool tieneParametros = false;
    std::queue<std::string> retorno;

    for (auto &&i : comandoEntero)
        if (i == '<' or i == '[')
            tieneParametros = true;
        else if (tieneParametros and std::string(" []<>").find(i) == size_t(-1))
            argumento.push_back(i);

        else if (tieneParametros and i == ' ') {
            std::cout << "HOLAAAAAAA\n";
            retorno.push(argumento);
            argumento.clear();
            tieneParametros = false;
        }

    std::stringstream(comandoEntero) >> comandoNombre;
    const std::vector<std::string> cmd = {"ayuda",        "login",
                                          "logout",       "listar_buses",
                                          "listar_rutas", "listar_viajes"};

    return std::make_pair(
        static_cast<Comando>(std::find(cmd.begin(), cmd.end(), comandoNombre) -
                             cmd.begin()),
        retorno);
}

int main() {
    do {
        std::cout << "\n$ ";
        std::string comando;
        std::getline(std::cin, comando);

        switch (ProcesarComando(comando).first) {
        case AYUDA:

            break;
        case LOGIN:

            break;
        case LOGOUT:

            break;
        case LISTAR_BUSES:

            break;
        case LISTAR_RUTAS:

            break;
        case LISTAR_VIAJES:

            break;
        default: // case NULL_COMMAND:

        }
    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is extremely helpful, thanks for helping and answering, the thing is that I am not supose to use the String type! Since I start college everybody keeps telling to me that if I use that String type in c++ it will give me a lot of problems in the future, because it doesn't have the same flexibility as a char[] or char*

Comment: @Dacaramo I am using C++ for past 5-6 years. And nearly from the beginning I am using string class. Till date I haven't got a single problem with strings which cannot be resolved. `std::string` is quite an integral part of modern C++, saying that it causes problems is an amateur comment. Well, it's up to you what you wanna use. Not using string will only make the code long and, coding less efficient. Happy coding. :)

Comment: Naah, you're totally right I'll accept your answer, the thing is that i was afraid of use it because all the time at college my teachers told me not to use the string type...About my problem, I figure it out, and I made it using std::string, it's true that it's a pretty powerful and useful class in modern C++. Thanks again for the help, from now and so on I will always use it in my C++ proyects. Thanks for the implementation I found it very useful to fix my problem.